# Imported Worksheet Randomly Inserted as First Sheet Instead of Last

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping some code through many workbooks, on 2 separate PC's. On one PC, I keep on getting an error- not on every loop, but randomly every 3rd or 4th loop. My code is supposed to find and import a worksheet from a different workbook, and the imported sheet is supposed to be placed last. For some reason, on this one PC, it sometimes places the sheet first, which throws off all the subsequent code. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Here is the code that is importing the worksheet:

```
Sub Step2Importsheet()

Sheets.Add Type:= _
"D:\Users\Desktop\Macro Data\Test\" & Range("E2").Text & ".csv"
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Columns("A").Replace "^", vbNullString, xlPart, xlByRows, True
Range("AA1").Value = "Function"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the different PC's using the same versions of Excel?

Comment: Yes, they are..

Comment: I suspect the problem is with unqualified objects (workbooks, worksheets, ranges) or with that `ActiveSheet`. Both are not ideal - especially when multiple books are in play

Comment: In my experience, importing a new sheet will always turn it into the activesheet. Do you think that's not the case here? What I find most intriguing is that it only happens sporadically, not with every workbook....

Comment: If you don't end up determining why it's throwing an error for `Activeworkbook.Worksheets.Count`, you can try defining the sheets by name, set as a variable, e.g., `set ws = workbooks("NAME").sheets("name")`.  additionally,

Comment: @Cyril, I'm running the code on hundreds of workbooks. I always use the sheet index, as names vary by workbook, but the placement of the sheet is what defines its purpose.

Comment: Have you tried to use a variable like `wscount = worksheets.count` and `debug.print wscount` to see if you are getting the appropriate count?

Comment: I would start by qualifying those objects. I see `Sheets`, `Columns`, & `Range` that are error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the job:

```
Sub Step2Importsheet()

Sheets.Add Type:= _
"D:\Users\Desktop\Macro Data\Test\" & Range("E2").Text & ".csv"

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

ws.Move After:=Worksheets(2)


ws.Columns("A").Replace "^", vbNullString, xlPart, xlByRows, True
ws.Range("AA1").Value = "Function"
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Sheets.Add` will be adding the sheet to whatever workbook happens to be active at that time. A better solution would be to have a `ByVal book As Workbook` parameter, then you can do `Set ws = book.Worksheets.Add` (I doubt this `Type:={path string}` is doing what you think it does) and move it `After:=book.Worksheets(2)`, making everything much more robust.

Comment: Also note the inconsistency between `Sheets` and `Worksheets` usage. Pick one, stick to it... keeping in mind that `Sheets` collection can contain `Chart` and about half a dozen legacy non-worksheet sheet types. If you are working with `Worksheets`, use the `Worksheets` collection.

Comment: FYI the `Type` named argument to `Sheets.Add` can take one of the [XlSheetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheettype) enum values. This file/path argument is definitely not doing what you think it does.